# How could I use one view to edit 2 different classes that have a common base class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Well, I need to create two questionnaires that are almost equals. The difference are that one have a question more than the other. So I created a class with only the ID (to persistence) to be the base class for both:

```
public class BaseQuizzClass{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

And then I created the classes, with almost the same names for the variables ( I thought that it could help using razor):

```
public class Quizz1 : BaseQuizzClass{

   [Display(Name="QuestionHere")]
   public string q1 {get;set;}

   [Display(Name="QuestionHere")]
   public string q2 {get;set;}

   ...

   [Display(Name="QuestionHere")]
   public string q9 {get;set;}
}

public class Quizz2 : BaseQuizzClass{
   [Display(Name="QuestionHere")]
   public string q1 {get;set;}

   [Display(Name="QuestionHere")]
   public string q2 {get;set;}

   ...

   [Display(Name="QuestionHere")]
   public string q9 {get;set;}

   [Display(Name="QuestionHere")]
   public string q10 {get;set;}
}
```

Then I created a View using the BaseQuizzClass as model, so I could pass an child class as parameter toit. But I don't know how to access the childs class attributes.

OBS.: Each question has your own text, defined in the Display annotation.

There's any way to do what I want? (I'm not pretty sure if I was clear)

Comment: You could use custom EditorFor templates for "Quizz1" and "Quizz2" but you're going to run in to a problem on the POST if you don't use unique action names for saving them. The only thing Quizz1 and Quizz2 have in common is that they are a BaseQuizzClass and as such, a view that edits "BaseQuizzClass" could only have the ID property. Your POST action can't accept "BaseQuizzClass" because you'll lose all of the properties that don't belong to the base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably switch the model up a bit:

```
public class QuestionClass
{
  public String Question { get; set; }

  public String Answer { get; set; }
}

public class QuizzClass
{
  public Int32 ID { get; set; }

  [UIHint("Question")]
  public IList<QuestionClass> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a view for the question, and instead of using the `[DisplayAttribute]` using the "key/value" setup of the object.

```
// ~/Views/_controller_/_action_.cshtml
@model QuizzClass

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for (var q = 0; q < Model.Questions.Length; q++)
  {
    // ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Question.cshtml
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Questions[q]);
  }
}
```

It just appears over-kill to have that much similarity, yet explicitly calling out each question in your "different" objects.

Comment: Well... I'll remap my models so. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think your architecture is faulty. Why not just have a class with a collection that holds your questions?

Comment: Yeah... you and Brad Christie are right... Thanks for the answer!